# Why PWA app create ShourtCut instead of install apk (Android version 9)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, progressive-web-apps

I created pwa from scratch it is worked and installed well in other device , but my MI android phone create shourtcut only.
Brand : REDMI 5 PRO
Android Version : 9

```
{
  "short_name": "os",
  "name": "os",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-256x256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#33D5AC",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "orientation": "portrait-primary"
}
```